# loop too many redirects when checkout in magento 1.9.3

Tags: checkout, redirection, magento-1.9.3.2

I have a newly installed magento 1.9.3.2 on MacOS 10.11 server. Also installed a certificate to run the site via https.

Everything works fine except for when I go to the cart and click on checkout. The page won't load and displays an too many redirections error.
No plugins have been installed, yet. Please see picture for my settings

Can anyone help me get dis sorted, please?
[image: Please see picture for my settings]

Comment: Did you clear caches after making changes to any config values?

Comment: Yes, I did, as well reindex